# validation using error provider and stop further execution

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to validate winform using error provider. When user click on button multiple Validated methods are executed `txtFieldOne_Validated(this, e); txtFieldTwo_Validated(this, e);` and I need solution to stop execution further if any of this validators fails and display error using error provider.

I thought to use private variable bool _formValid like

```
private btnValidateFields_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   txtFieldOne_Validated(this, e); 
   txtFieldTwo_Validated(this, e);  
   if(_formValid)
   {continue...}
}

private void txtFieldOne_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(....)
        errorProvider1.SetError(txtFieldOne, "some error message")
       _formValid = true;
    else(....)
       errorProvider1.SetError(txtFieldOne, "")
       formValid = false;
}
```

but using this approach if last checked field was true than populated _formValid remains true and form pass.

Comment: Please define `further execution`. If you dont call anything else after that then nothing should execute.

Comment: I should call further execution inside if formValid statement, to populate my object with user input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not clear what you are trying to do. But as per your comments, I will suggest something like this.There is no need to call different Validation method for different controls. All controls should be validated in same method.

```
void IsFormValid(this, e)
{
    bool result = ValidateAllControls();

    if(!result)
        return;

    // Rest of the execution
}

bool ValidateAllControls()
{
    if(!control1.IsValid)
        return false;
    if(!control2.IsValid)
        return false;
    if(!control3.IsValid)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Let me know if I misunderstood something.

Hope it helps.